# Assume that f is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ then f is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Assume that f is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ then f is uniformly continuous

since given  $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ then

$\forall \epsilon 0, \exists M>0, \forall x>M,|f(x)|<\epsilon $

i did't get any ideal any help .thank you...

Comment: Do you know, and are you allowed to use, the theorem that a continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous?